# Have you seen this formula for factorial?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Let $p$ always be a prime.  $n! = \prod_{p\leq n}p^{\lfloor \frac{n}{p}\rfloor}$.  Then $\binom{n}{r} = \prod_{p\leq r}p^{\lfloor n/p \rfloor -\lfloor (n-r)/p \rfloor - \lfloor r/p \rfloor} \times ...$  It's kind of long to write out but there are two other product symbols with ranges $n-r \lt p \leq n$ and $r \lt p \leq n-r$.

Comment: The first formula is wrong for $n \geq 4$.

Comment: How is it wrong?  $n!$ is a product of primes.  The prime $p$ occurs approx $n/p$ times, and there's no danger of overcounting because we're using primes.

Comment: Wrong, as in it's not right.  E.g., $4!=24$ and $\prod_{p \leq 4} p^{\lfloor 4/p \rfloor}=2^2 \times 3=12$.

Comment: Crap, i see, it is wrong.  Thanks

Comment: I'm wondering if it can be fixed by using something like "prime power p" or something similar.  It's still not right, but a correction term perhaps could be introduced.

Comment: The highest exponent of $p$ in $m!$ is $\lfloor \frac{m}{p}\rfloor+\lfloor \frac{m}{p^2}\rfloor+\cdots$. From this one can get a similar more complicated looking formula for the highest power of $p$ that divides a binomial coefficient.

Comment: This works then: $n!=\prod_{p^a \leq n} p^{\lfloor n/p^a \rfloor}$ where the sum is over all primes $p$ and $a \geq 1$ such that $p^a \leq n$.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to work.  I'm using this to try and analyse a complicated binomial sum in another post.

Comment: $p^\alpha \leq n$ is not necessary. If $p^\alpha > n$ the term contributes nothing.

Comment: Dear EM, If you want to analyze prime powers dividing $n^!$, there is a variant of your formula which is standard, and perhaps more helpful: let $s(n)$ denote the sum of the digits of $n$, *when* $n$ *is written in base* $p$.  Then the largest power of $p$ (a prime) dividing $n!$ equals $(n - s(n))/(p-1)$.  I've frequently found this helpful in studying binomial-type coefficients.  Regards,

Comment: Thank you!  I encountered that before when studying p-adic notes.  I don't know which version will be more helpful yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments we have that

$$ 
n! = \prod_{p\,\,prime}\prod_{k\geq 1}p^{\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k}\rfloor}$$

Alternatively, if we let $k_p(n)$ be the highest power of $p$ dividing $n$.  We have $k_p(n) = \sum_{k\geq 1} \lfloor \frac{n}{p^k}\rfloor$ and

$$
n! = \prod_{p\,\,prime}p^{k_p(n)}$$

A bound on $k$ in the sum can be made and also the bound $p \leq n$ can be imposed.  And we can come up with a formula for $\binom{n}{r}$.  We have for $r \lt n-r$

$$
\binom{n}{r} = (\prod_{n-r\lt p\leq n} p^{k_p(n)})(\prod_{r\lt p\leq n-r} p^{k_p(n) - k_p(n-r)})(\prod_{p\leq r}p^{k_p(n)-k_p(n-r)-k_p(r)})
$$

We assumed $r \lt n-r$.  If that's not the case then substitute $n-r$ where you see $r$ and vise versa and use the formula $\binom{n}{n-r} = \binom{n}{r}$.